# TelegramBot C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

Взял [API](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot) для C# c официального сайта Telegram.

При создании консольного приложения для приема сообщений боту хватало записи:

```
Bot.StartReceiving();
Console.ReadLine();
Bot.StopReceiving();
```

Но в проекте с WinForm строка `Console.ReadLine();`
не считывает значения.

На что ее заменить? Или нужен другой принцип?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` - для работы с консолью.  С консолью, Карл!

Answer (score 2):

При запуске формы запускаете получение, при закрытии формы - останавливаете. Как-то так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Telegram.Bot.Api bot;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("your API access Token");
        bot.StartReceiving();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        bot.StopReceiving();
    }
}
```